# SICP Lisp/Scheme - recursive return value gets lost

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, lisp, sicp

I'm writing a simple function that recursively checks if `x` (a list) is an element of `remaining` (list of lists).

Somehow, the `#f` return from innermost frame doesn't properly bubble up to the top:

```
#lang sicp

(define (was_seen? remaining x)
  (cond ((null? remaining) #false)
        ((eq? (car remaining) x) #true)
        ((was_seen? (cdr remaining) x))
  )
)


; test variables

(define seen (list(list 'a)))
(define z (list 0))


; now the test

(was_seen? seen z)
; expected: #f; returns blank (evaluated to #void when seen via debugger)


(was_seen? (cdr seen) z)
; expected: #f; returns #f as it should. 
; This is what the inner (recursive) call - correctly - evaluates to. 
; It's just that this #f doesn't get properly returned to the global caller?
```

It must be something stupid simple, but I cannot find what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hint: what does the `((was_seen? (cdr remaining) x))` clause return?

Comment: Why do you return false when `(null? x)`? A list of lists can contain an empty list.

Comment: @coredump in this case it will evaluate to `#false`, since `(cdr remaining)` is empty, so it will hit the 2nd predicate of `cond`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cond` returns the value from the body of the first clause whose condition is truthy (i.e. not `#f`), or the value of the `else` clause if none of them are truthy.

If none of the conditions are truthy, and there's no `else` clause, it returns `#void`.

In your case, none of the conditions is ever true, since the recursive call is false.

Change the last clause to be an `else` clause so the value of the recursive call will be returned.

```
(define (was_seen? remaining x)
  (cond ((null? remaining) #false)
        ((eq? (car remaining) x) #true)
        (else (was_seen? (cdr remaining) x))
  )
)
```

You may think you were depending on the shortcut that the value of the condition is returned if there's no body in the clause. But that only happens when the condition is truthy, so that this is the clause that's going to return a value. It doesn't apply when the condition is false.

Comment: The report does not specify the return to be `#void`. It calls it the undefined value and its deliberately underspecified. MIT Scheme returns logical values no developer should use since it makes the programs implementation specific. It is suggested in later reports that the unspecified value be the same object returned, but it is not an requirement. I usually like `"BaNaNa"` as the unspecified value so no `#void` from my implementations :-p

Comment: @Sylwester I was simplifying, since the actual returned value is not relevant, just the reason why it's not returning what he expected.